# Laravel Vapor + S3 bucket for static images - use domain url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

First time working with `AWS`, `S3` & `Lambda`, using `Laravel Vapor`.

Firstly, my domain is held by an external registrar. I have setup a subdomain to point to the `Laravel Vapor` app in `AWS` (whose root folder is a different `S3` bucket).

```
https://subdomain.mydomain.com
```

The app has an `S3` bucket to host a few images for an app, and would like to have the images resolved using the base url for the app + `/images/` path. The `S3` bucket has the pics inside a `/images` folder :

```
https://subdomain.mydomain.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/images
```

with

```
https://subdomain.mydomain.com/images
```

This may be a basic question, but I have been unable to figure it out looking at AWS's Virtual Hosting docs for `S3`. Any pointers / suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I think you cloud do this through CloudFront. Have you considered that?

Comment: Yes I have but same issue. CloudFront is a CDN layer on the S3 bucket, so how to redirect the base url with subdomain and images path to the CloudFront / S3?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for I believe. I wouldn't advise you do it this way but if it's required to serve your images from your local domain you could try this.

https://medium.com/@poursio/serving-static-files-from-your-root-domain-in-laravel-vapor-42547a41f5ec